# Tomcat with HTTPS REST Setup

Tags: rest, tomcat, ssl, https, jersey

I'm writing a REST server using Jersey for Tomcat. I'm proficient in Java but this is my first time writing for web, so I hope this question isn't dumb. I've tried searching all over but can't come up with an answer I understand well.

I'm trying to utilize HTTPS and basic auth, but I don't know if I have to write anything in the actual Java to accomplish this. Does Tomcat take care of all encryption/decryption of SSL info, or do I have to do something in my server code to take care of this? In the client I know I will have do this manually, but I can't find anything about how to do this on the server end. Is it a Tomcat setting? Do I have to set Tomcat to only forward HTTPS traffic to my server, and then it will decrypt and send the decrypted information to my server, where it will act just as though it was a regular unencrypted command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server, you first need to make sure Tomcat is configured to support HTTPS/SSL/TLS. This includes setting up the keystore and editing a configuration file. You can see all the details of how to do that at [SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). Note that link is for Tomcat 8. For Tomcat 7, you should search for the according docs.

Once you have that set up, all there is left to do to actually make use the HTTPS, is to set the `<transport>` to `CONFIDENTIAL` in the web.xml file of your web application.

```
<security-constraint>
    ...
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

If you have never set up the web.xml seucurity yet, then you'll want take time to read [Securing Web Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm#GKBAA). There is also a section on setting up Basic auth with web.xml configuration.

When you get the section about Basic auth, you will notice a configuration of `<realm-name>`. The realm is something that needs to be set up with Tomcat. This is basically the access point to the store of users that Tomcat will lookup the authenticate. To read more about setting up a realm, see [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html) (again this is a Tomcat 8 link). There different types of realms to choose from, so just pick one, like the JDBC realm.

And that's it. Rather than give a tutorial, I think the links I provided are goods officials sources that will do a better job at explaining than I could do. If this is all new to you, it might take you a day to set everything up, but I'm sure you will learn a lot from those documentations.

Another thing, if you want to do authorization, once you set up the realm in tomcat with roles (see example in JDBC realm section), you can either use the roles authorization configuration in the web.xml (see "Securing Web Applications" link) or you can use Jersey's role based authorization, which will give a little more fine control. For that see [Authorization - securing resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12285)

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! Could I also allow Apache to handle HTTPS and then only allow Apache to forward HTTPS traffic to tomcat?

Comment: Honestly I don't work much with Apache, so I couldn't say.